# Keyboard not responding on startup

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, boot, dell-vostro

I’m having a weird problem with one of the laptops at my work. Every now and then (not a systematic repeating pattern, but kind of random) the keyboard will not function on start up.

The computer boots and it gets to the CTRL + ALT + DELETE screen and it is responding to nothing from the keyboard. The mouse works fine. I then try to force a shutdown and reboot the machine and most of the time it then works.

My first thought was that it was a hardware malfunction with the keyboard hardware but it seems strange that the computer can be stationed for several days without being removed and it still “loses” connection to the keyboard.

The OS is Windows 7 Pro and it is a Dell Laptop Vostro.

Does anyone experienced this kind of problem with a laptop with/with out Windows 7 and maybe got a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a dell vostro 1000 with a keyboard problem, no response after startup. I have replaced the keyboard but that did not help. I try to leave my laptop on, because if it shuts down the keyboard will not work at all. I have to repeatedly do a shut down at least 4-5 times for the keyboard to finally work. It is very frustrating and getting worse. Especially since Dell laptops have an overheat problem too that makes them shut down whenever they want!

Found your post while I was looking for solutions to mine. I run windows xp. Wish I had a solution, so far have not found any that work. Most say it is motherboard issue, but my warranty is over and I don't want to pay for a new motherboard, might as well pay for a new laptop (not Dell) at that point!

Let's hope someone can help us!

Answer (score 2):

I have a Vostro and had the same issue. It would also strike mid session, not just at boot up.
Dell suggested a reinstall of OS (Win7 Pro) that seemed to help for a little while, but then it came back.
They then did some diagnostics and asked me to move my RAM into the other available slot. This seems to have made it much better. It does still happen very occasionally and I think this is due to me turning laptop on, then closing lid. When I reopen lid the laptop doesn't wake up properly, closing / reopening the lid often fixes, I rarely have to force it off now. I hope this helps.
I'm about to go to a clients office as they have 3 Vostros (all different models, all Win7 Pro) all with this issue. I hope my own answer fixes them or I'll be hunting for more suggestions.